# how to write a snippet than can toggle text like snippet Get Element

Tags: sublimetext3, sublimetext-snippet

In snippet `Get Element`, when i type `get` and push tab, it will show

```
getElementsByTagName('')
```

and the letter `T` is highlight and editable, then typed letter `I`, it will change to

```
getElementById('')
```

automatically.

I want to create a snippet which can toggle text by the letter i typed, just like the snippet `Get Element` do, but i can't find where the snippet location.
Anyone know its location or know how to create a snippet like that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The snippet is inside the archived JavaScript package, which is located in the installation directory, and then `Packages/JavaScript.sublime-package`. Inside that package, the file's name is `Snippets/Get-Elements.sublime-snippet` and it has the following contents:

```xml
<snippet>
    <content><![CDATA[getElement${1/(T)|.*/(?1:s)/}By${1:T}${1/(T)|(I)|.*/(?1:agName)(?2:d)/}('$2')]]></content>
    <tabTrigger>get</tabTrigger>
    <scope>source.js</scope>
    <description>Get Elements</description>
</snippet>
```

Basically, it works with conditional replace format strings. You can find the documentation for those in the [boost regex docs](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_64_0/libs/regex/doc/html/boost_regex/format/boost_format_syntax.html), however I suggest to just have two different snippets in this situation with the triggers `gett` and `geti` respectively, since those still require the same number of key strokes but are way easier to create and maintain.

---

You can open archived resource files like this easily with the [PackageResourceViewer package](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/PackageResourceViewer).

Details on what archived packages are: http://docs.sublimetext.info/en/latest/extensibility/packages.html